# REST API - Eager loading nested resources

Tags: postgresql, api, rest

I would like to know if I am correctly eager loading nested resources in my API.

In my app, `companies` can have many `technologies`, and `tools`. The relationship is stored in the join tables `companies_technologies` and `companies_tools`.

At an endpoint `/companies`, I would like to return all the `companies` and their `technologies` and `tools` like the following:

```
[
  {
    company_name: 'company_1',
    ...
    technologies: [
      {...},
      ...,
      {...}
    ],
    tools: [
      {...},
      ...,
      {...}
    ]
  },
  ..., 
  {
    company_name: 'company_n',
    ...
  }
]
```

To return 30 companies, I end up doing 61 queries.

- One query to get at most 30 companies (**1 query**)
- Loop through the companies to get the technologies for each of them. (**30 queries**)
- Loop through the companies to get the tools for each of them. (**30 queries**)

Then I build the response and send it back to the client.

The response time is very high even with indices on all foreign keys. Is doing that many query unavoidable for my API design, or is there an alternative approach?

Comment: To very simply make this three queries you could query all companies, then a join of companies to technologies, then a join of companies to tools.  Then iterate over them once each to build the response.  My SQL is a bit rusty but I'm sure it could be done in 1 query.  But 3 is far better than n*2+1.

Comment: is retrieving the technologies & tools in the same step mandatory? alternatively you could have a [link](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3) pointing to them and execute a targeted query only when drilling down